EWS JAVA API 2.0 forward email with incorrect timezone
I am writing a function in Java to forward Outlook emails. When using ews-java-api 2.0, I found that the time zone of the original email's sent time attached to the forwarded email is UTC, not the UTC+8 time zone where I am located. Is there any way to solve this? Thank you!
This my pom.xml：
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>
            <artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

This my code：
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(exchangeService, new ItemId(this.messageId));
ResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
responseMessage = message.createForward();
MessageBody messageBody = new MessageBody();
messageBody.setBodyType(BodyType.HTML);
messageBody.setText(html);
responseMessage.setSubject(this.subject);
responseMessage.setBodyPrefix(messageBody);
setResponseMessageRecipients(responseMessage);
responseMessage.sendAndSaveCopy();

I tried setting the time zone to UTC+8 before initializing ExchangeService and changed my computer's time zone to UTC, but the sent time of the original email did not change.
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8");
        TimeZone.setDefault(tz);


You need to use ZonedDateTime class and convert the utc time to gmt+8:
ZoneId baseSystemTimeZone =  ZoneId.of("UTC");
ZoneId targetZoneId =ZoneId.of("GMT+8");
            
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.parse("date-time",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")), baseSystemTimeZone);
Instant instant = Instant.from(zonedDateTime);
ZonedDateTime zd =  instant.atZone(targetZoneId);

